# Android capturing scan data before entered in edittext field

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext, visual-studio-2017, barcode-scanner

What actually happens is the device sends 2 enters or tabs after scan based on whether it is set to send tab or enter.

I building with xamarin Android namespaces

I've tried everything possible, I've set my fragment as a textwatcher

```
public class SearchFragment : BaseFragment, IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListener, ITextWatcher
```

and set up a listener

```
this._theEditText.AddTextChangedListener(this);
```

and set it up in the BeforeTextChanged Event, however cannot get the values from the char sequence although in the test case the scan has 8 characters, +2 for 2 enter keys, but it comes across as 8.

```
    public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
        this._scanCount = _scanCount + (after - start);
        if (this._scanCount > 4)
        {
            string text = s.ToString();
            //need remove carriage returns and line feeds here if exist
            //then add single carriage return or advance to next field
        }

        if (this._scanTimer != null) this._scanTimer.Dispose();
        this._scanTimer = new Timer(delegate (object state)
        {
            this._scanCount = 0;
            this._scanTimer = null;
        }, false, 100, 0);
    }
```

Next methods I used were capturing keypress and using the editText built in beforetextchanged event handler (I've used all these different methods separately, not all together)

```
this._theEditText.KeyPress += EditText_KeyPress;
this._theEditText.BeforeTextChanged += EditText_BeforeTextChanged;
```

with the keypressed event I just got a bunch of tabs and f4's (I might add these tabs didn't advance the field oddly enough)

with the BeforeTextChanged event again I could not get the character sequence although there was a difference in the before and after of 8 (again enters at end did not count) although there was a difference of 8 the actually text e.Text is ""

```
    private void EditText_BeforeTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._scanCount = _scanCount + (e.AfterCount - e.BeforeCount);
        if (this._scanCount > 4)
        {
            SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = (SpannableStringBuilder)e.Text;

            ((SpannableStringBuilder)e.Text).ToString();
        }

        if (this._scanTimer != null) this._scanTimer.Dispose();
        this._scanTimer = new Timer(delegate (object state)
        {
            this._scanCount = 0;
            this._scanTimer = null;
        }, false, 100, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Which barcode scanner are you working with?

Comment: it's a speeddata device, I'm trying to set it up so it doesn't matter which device though as all devices may behave a little different where this one was the case where I realized I need to handle the incoming data

Comment: Ok makes sense, then using an API is out of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, keyboard-scanners and Android are quite a mess together.The scanners I had to deal with used to send Down+Enter as a sign they finished the scan. Here's the Java code that works (I believe you'll have no problem translating this to C# and changing the Down/Enter to your two keys)

```
public class ScannerView extends View implements View.OnKeyListener {
    private StringBuilder scannedCode = new StringBuilder();
    private Callback scanCallback;


    public void setCallback(Callback scanCallback) {
        this.scanCallback = scanCallback;
    }

    public ScannerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ScannerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ScannerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ScannerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        requestFocus();
        setOnKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean consumed = false;
        if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            return consumed;
        }

        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_6:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_7:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_8:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9:
                scannedCode.append(keyCode - 7);
                consumed = true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                if (scanCallback != null) {
                    scanCallback.onBarcodeScanned(scannedCode.toString());
                }
                scannedCode = new StringBuilder();
                consumed = true;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                consumed = true;
                break;
        }

        return consumed;
    }

    interface Callback {
        void onBarcodeScanned(String barCode);
    }
}
```

from what I learned, this is as close as you can get to a good, retail-like experience with scanners. You can then use the callback and set the text to whatever edit you need or process it. Just remember to set focus to your scanview all the time: parent lifecycle events, its own focus change callback and so on, you'll figure out the rest while testing.

Comment: That's pretty awesome and completely performs the task I was looking for capturing the keypresses and consuming them or not, however I have found that the scanner is only sending an F4.  I have no idea where the text is coming from or how to capture it now.  haha.

Comment: what do you mean only an f4? nothing else? capture it by attaching a callback to the scanview.

Comment: Yeh, it sends an f4... I think what this device is doing is scanning th ebarcode then copying the scan to the clipboard then sends the f4 which on this device may be paste which isn't a keypress event  (or something to that effect)

What I've done is used your method and set the control to ignore tab and enter keypresses then I setup a before textChanged event to get the text before a change then compared that to the value in the textChangedEvent.  If it was a large change (more than 3 characters it moves to the next field.

Comment: @JessieLulham so is it a keyboard scanner or not after all? connect it to a PC and scan something in a text document to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned there are no barcode scanners that send the data the same way. As Nick's answer noted, there are some that send key codes, but the ones I've dealt with send tabs, newlines,  carriage returns, and even spaces to prefix/postfix a barcode string and you get the entire string in one shot.

A text watcher can deal with these cleanly.

#### Subclass a Java object and implement ITextWatcher:

```
public class StripperTextWatcher : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
{
    char[] stripThese = new char[] { '\n', '\t', '\r', ' ' };

    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length(); i++)
        {
            if (stripThese.Contains(s.ElementAt(i)))
            {
                s.Replace(i, i + 1, "");
                return; // AfterTextChanged is called recursively for each change.... 
            }
        }

    }

    public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    public void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
var editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
editText.AddTextChangedListener(new StripperTextWatcher());
```

Comment: the problem with text inputs and watchers is they skip chars when cant manage the input they are receiving fast enough(10 ms delay between "typed" chars)

Comment: @Nick Never has been a problem for me as the entire barcode string is sent from scanner and entered in one "paste" (i.e. usually within one UI Looper cycle) and also in using `AfterTextChanged`, it will always get called recursively if that does not happen and it spreads across a couple/few Looper cycles...

Comment: looks like you had a friendly scanner then. you could see the chars appearing one by one with most of the ones I had to deal with. I agree it might work normally on a proper device in a few tests, but a production environment that scans 10k items a day and has to cancel/edit receipts due to a scan error will most definitely send back mixed reviews. trust me, I had to learn it the hard way. fun fact: even with the checksum, wrong codes do get scanned :)

Comment: @Nick hahaha, yea, I know about wrong scans and *low-cost* scanners ;-) I did a production line scanner system that used Android hosts (NOT my choice) and each one scanned 50k+ items a day (24x7), each item had three bar codes and each had to "post" in real-time as conveyor diverters used the info also.... As a side note, standard Xamarin failed big time in that environment but as a prototype it was up and running in a couple of days, Java kind-of worked, but every now and then dalvik would puke, in the end, a NDK-only app using a custom Xamarin/Mono with statically linked scanner c libs...

Comment: This actually won't work on capturing the tab as tab isn't actually written to the text it is captured at some point after keydown and advances field

Comment: @JessieLulham That depends upon how you are validating and releasing the field, but yes if you are allowing the focus to change this would not work with your layout configuration and scanner.